# VS Code debugging razor(cshtml)

Tags: .net, razor, asp.net-core-2.0

When debugging .net core 2.0 webapp in VS Code I seem to not be able to debug .cshtml files, it just says "No symbols have been loaded for this document". Noted that lots of people had similar problems, yet I could not find any solution. Help?

Answer (score 0):

In launch.json file, section ".NET Core Launch (web)", set the sourceFileMap Views path to your project with views to debug.
Ex.: in my case :

```
"sourceFileMap": {
    "/Views": "${workspaceRoot}/src/SoftinuxBase.Security/Views"
}
```

The problem is you can't debug view of other projects in same time.
Personally, I did not find how to do it.

Keep in mind that the startup project must contain the pdb files of all the projects of your solution in his build folder